# How to get access to JwtToken to check with blacklist within nestjs passport strategy?

Tags: passport.js, nestjs, passport-jwt

I'm trying to check for blacklisted JWT tokens within JWTStrategy. `jwtFromRequest` doesn't take an async function, so I can't check it there.

`validate` function gives access to JWT payload and not the token.

Below is my sample code.

```js
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(
    private readonly configService: ConfigService<AppJWTSettings>,
    @Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private readonly cache: Cache,
  ) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(), // Returns the encoded JWT string or null.
      ignoreExpiration: false, // validate the expiration of the token.
      // https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication#implementing-passport-jwt
      // PEM-encoded public key
      secretOrKey: configService.get<string>('JWT_PUBLIC_KEY'),
      algorithms: ['RS256'],
    });
  }

  /**
   * Passport will build a user object based on the return value of our validate() method,
   * and attach it as a property on the Request object.
   *
   * @param payload JWT payload
   */
  async validate(payload: JwtPayload): Promise<JwtUser> {
    const user = { id: payload.sub, iat: payload.iat };
    return user;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is one option with `secretOrKeyProvider`. Here is an example:

```ts
@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor(
    private readonly configService: ConfigService<AppJWTSettings>,
    @Inject(CACHE_MANAGER) private readonly cache: Cache,
  ) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(), // Returns the encoded JWT string or null.
      ignoreExpiration: false, // validate the expiration of the token.
      // https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication#implementing-passport-jwt
      // PEM-encoded public key
      secretOrKeyProvider: (
        _request: Request,
        rawJwtToken: any,
        done: (err: any, secretOrKey?: string | Buffer) => void,
      ) => {
        // Check if your token is blocked here!!!
        void isBlocked(rawJwtToken).then(isBlocked => {
          if (isBlocked) {
            done(new Error("This token is blocked"));
          } else {
            done(null, configService.get<string>('JWT_PUBLIC_KEY'));
          }
        });
      },
      algorithms: ['RS256'],
    });
  }

  /**
   * Passport will build a user object based on the return value of our validate() method,
   * and attach it as a property on the Request object.
   *
   * @param payload JWT payload
   */
  async validate(payload: JwtPayload): Promise<JwtUser> {
    const user = { id: payload.sub, iat: payload.iat };
    return user;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When a new token is created, I store the token in a cookie and pass the token via AJAX calls and sometimes pass it around via query string requests.  You should just be able to pass whatever token the user is using via cookies (headers), query string etc...  On the controller, have it validated, if blacklisted return a redirect url or string on unauthorized and redirect via JavaScript.

Comment: Validating in controller doesn't follow the DRY approach. In each and every protected route, this check needs to be added. I can even create a separate Guard to check for blacklisted JWTs and pass as an additional guard in UseGuards. I'm looking to solve within this Guard.

Comment: Typically, the only significant difference in the validate() method for each strategy is how you determine if a user exists and is valid. For example, in a JWT strategy, depending on requirements, we may evaluate whether the userId carried in the decoded token matches a record in our user database, or matches a list of revoked tokens. This is an excerpt from NestJs Official docs. https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication#implementing-passport-local

I'm looking for their recommended way of matching revoked tokens.